# Does no work correctly: Application.StartupPath

Tags: c#, .net, installation, startup

I have a C# program created with Visual Studio 2012. Gender installer with Install Shield, and it turns out that when looking for the path to the database, the program always generates the path ... Although my computer run it in other computers.

I do not understand why this is happening, since I use the function:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

That is supposed to take the path of each user running the program.

Why is it not working properly?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a rights problem. If the program runs in a limited rights "sandbox" via UAC it can happen, that the path are different, because of Shadow-Copy and such.

You can try to use the following:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

**BUT**

Is it wise to save the DB in the application folder? If the user is not an admin he can not write there => `%APPDATA%` should be used, see e.g. [Modify path string to improve robustness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222837/modify-path-string-to-improve-robustness/23222922#23222922)